# Delphi Chromium Embedded - Refresh page with F5

Tags: delphi, page-refresh, chromium-embedded

I am using Delphi Chromium Embedded in my application, and I have the following question:
How can I emulate F5 key to refresh page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [`OnKeyEvent`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/%28default%29/CefKeyboardHandler.html) use the following code:

```
uses
  CEFLib;

procedure TForm1.Chromium1KeyEvent(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; event: TCefHandlerKeyEventType; code,
  modifiers: Integer; isSystemKey: Boolean; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  if (event = KEYEVENT_RAWKEYDOWN) and (code = VK_F5) then
  begin
    Result := True;
    Chromium1.Browser.Reload;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

@TLama
maybe the right code is like this(in dcef3 using delphi7):

```
    if (event^.kind = KEYEVENT_RAWKEYDOWN) and (event^.windows_key_code = VK_F5) then
```